# Rolling a die. Math problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics

Consider the experiment of rolling a die until "6" appears. How many outcomes are in the event that exactly four rolls are required to get a "6"?

Comment: the answer is $5 \times 5 \times 5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the game to stop at the 4th turn $6$ must come at the fourth position and no 6 should come before it so the first 3 outcomes can conatain any number except 6 thus the answer is $5 \times 5 \times 5=125
$

Comment: Thank you. that was helpful

Comment: @bonny If an answer solves your problem, you should accept it by clicking on the checkmark.  That way, everyone can see it has been solved.